# Cannot get images to display in Django(1.3) project

Tags: django, django-templates

I'm making a simple Django project but I cannot get any images to display in my pages.

Django documentation at https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/howto/static-files/#basic-usage states

> Basic usage Put your static files somewhere that staticfiles will find
>   them.
>
> By default, this means within static/ subdirectories of apps in your
>   INSTALLED_APPS.
>
> Your project will probably also have static assets that aren’t tied to
>   a particular app. The STATICFILES_DIRS setting is a tuple of
>   filesystem directories to check when loading static files. It’s a
>   search path that is by default empty. See the STATICFILES_DIRS docs
>   how to extend this list of additional paths.
>
> Additionally, see the documentation for the STATICFILES_FINDERS
>   setting for details on how staticfiles finds your files.
>
> Make sure that django.contrib.staticfiles is included in your
>   INSTALLED_APPS.
>
> For local development, if you are using runserver or adding
>   staticfiles_urlpatterns to your URLconf, you’re done with the setup –
>   your static files will automatically be served at the default (for
>   newly created projects) STATIC_URL of /static/.
>
> You’ll probably need to refer to these files in your templates. The
>   easiest method is to use the included context processor which allows
>   template code like:
>
> See Referring to
>   static files in templates for more details, including an alternate
>   method using a template tag.

So I did this in settings.py:

```
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    '/home/abc/django/project1/media/',
)
```

and enabled `'django.contrib.staticfiles',`
In media, I have a folder img, which has various jpg files.

In my template, I have this as one of the lines:

```
<img src="{{STATIC_URL}}img/{{var}}.jpg">
```

When I'm passing var to this template via my view.

The HTML page seems to render this tag as `"<img src="img/abc.jpg">` where var="abc".
But my browser refuses to display the image. What have I done wrong?

Answer (score 3):

Did you see ths part in the documentation:

If `{{ STATIC_URL }}` isn't working in your template, you're probably not using RequestContext when rendering the template.

Do you also use RequestContext in your view to render the template?

Comment: I did try that, but it didn't work either. My settings.py did not have "TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS" at all. Manually adding it made no difference. However using "{% load static %}
<img src="{% get_static_prefix %}images/hi.jpg" />" does display the images. But I didn't really understand why the first method doesn't work. Oh well.

Comment: Can you show your view? TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS is not in the settings.py by default. When you add django.core.context_processors.static only it doesnt work either. You should include the whole list in your setings.py: TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS = (
    'django.core.context_processors.debug',
    'django.core.context_processors.i18n',
    'django.core.context_processors.media',
    'django.core.context_processors.static',
    'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
    'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
)

Answer (score 0):

Here is an alternative approach:

settings.py:

```
import os
PROJECT_DIR = os.path.dirname(__file__) + '/../'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(PROJECT_DIR, 'media/')
STATIC_URL = '/media/'
```

In your template:

```
{% load staticfiles %}
<img src="{% static img/foo.jpg %}" />
```

If you need to pass a variable, use the prefix method:

```
{% load staticfiles %}
<img src="{% get_static_prefix %}img/{{var}}.jpg" />
```